# How can I test a Kotlin flow builder with delay() calls?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow, turbine

I have a piece of code in an Android Kotlin project similar to below, where I use the `flow` builder method to generate an infinite loop of periodic emissions:

```kotlin
fun doSomething(): Flow<Int> = flow {
 var i = 0
  while (true) {
    emit(i++)
    delay(5000L)
  }
}
```

I am then trying to unit test this flow using the (very useful!) [Turbine](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine) library, as below:

```kotlin
@Test
fun myTest() = runTest {
  doSomething().test {
    assertEquals(expected = 0, actual = awaitItem())
    assertEquals(expected = 1, actual = awaitItem())
    assertEquals(expected = 2, actual = awaitItem())
    cancelAndIgnoreRemainingEvents()
  }
}
```

My understanding of the `runTest` method from the coroutines-test library is that it automatically skips any calls to `delay` within that scope, but the above test is failing with a timeout exception. I've tried littering log statements throughout, and only the first `assertEquals` call is being triggered. The latter two are never reached because the call to `delay` from within the flow is apparently blocking the test.

Is this expected behaviour when working with a Flow builder? If so, is there any way of controlling the passage of time in my scenario?

Comment: There are [some conditions](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/) for `runTest` to be able to skip delays. Do you change the Dispatcher at any point? As another simple check, does a test that only has `= runTest { delay(100_000) }` skip the delay? And yes, there are methods for advancing time (see the docs my first link), but they require the test Dispatcher is set.

Comment: @aSemy Thanks for the reply, I tried your suggestion and it passes perfectly fine. However if I place that same block into a flow builder like:
```
flow {
    emit(0)
    delay(5000L)
    emit(1)
    delay(5000L)
    emit(2)
}
```
it doesn't skip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in Turbine 0.8.0 and 0.9.0-SNAPSHOT. It doesn't inherit the test configuration, which can skip the delays. See the issue here: https://github.com/cashapp/turbine/issues/84

If you want to test now, then you can do so manually.

```kotlin
import kotlin.test.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runTest

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class DelayTest {

    fun doSomething(): Flow<Int> = flow {
        var i = 0
        while (true) {
            println("${System.currentTimeMillis()} emitting $i")
            emit(i++)
            delay(5000L)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testFlow() = runTest {
        val result = doSomething().take(3).toList()

        assertEquals(listOf(0, 1, 2), result)
    }
}
```

Or, as a workaround, you can make the flow use the test dispatcher using [`flowOn()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow-on.html). This changes the context *upstream* and does not "leak downstream".

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun testFlowOnWorkaround() = runTest {
        val testFlow = doSomething()
            .flowOn(UnconfinedTestDispatcher(testScheduler))

        testFlow.test {
            assertEquals(expected = 0, actual = awaitItem())
            assertEquals(expected = 1, actual = awaitItem())
            assertEquals(expected = 2, actual = awaitItem())
            cancelAndIgnoreRemainingEvents()
        }
    }
```

As another workaround you can first collect the flow normally to a list. Thanks to `runTest{}` the delays are skipped. Then you can transform it back into a flow, and test that flow.

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun testFlowToListWorkaround() = runTest {
        val myFlow = doSomething().take(3).toList().asFlow()

        myFlow.test {
            assertEquals(expected = 0, actual = awaitItem())
            assertEquals(expected = 1, actual = awaitItem())
            assertEquals(expected = 2, actual = awaitItem())
            cancelAndIgnoreRemainingEvents()
        }
    }
```

Versions:

- Kotlin 1.6.21
- Coroutines 1.6.1
- Kotlin Test 1.6.21

Comment: That's a shame, much appreciated though!

Comment: Just seen the edit, got it working! This workaround doesn't work on 0.7.0 though, which was annoying me so much until I realised I was on the wrong version...